# Tracked changes

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I know and understand all (except one) of the points on https://logological.org/word giving reasons why we **shouldn't use Microsoft Word** documents as a portable way of sending files.

The only one that I didn't know was that

> **Microsoft Word** is often configured **by default** to **automatically track and record changes** you make to a document. What many people do not realize is that this record of changes is actually silently **embedded in the file** every time you save your document. When you send such a document to a third party, it is a **trivial matter** for them **to recover this log** and see how the document appeared **several revisions ago**. Thus compromising or confidential information you thought you removed from a document before sending it may in fact still be accessible to the recipient. Indeed, there have been at least a few high-profile cases of confidential information being leaked via publically-posted Word documents.

Emphasis mine.

How can I trivially recover this log that contains the revisions?
Preferably *without* Microsoft Word

Comment: That’s partly wrong. It is not by default configured to track. Only people that click all the buttons and forget what they do end up with that unknowingly. The default is _no tracking_, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Open XML Format uses zip compression technology to store documents.<sup>1</sup>

This means for Office documents with a file extension ending in "x", you can unzip them. If your context menu is setup to offer deflating anything (like with 7-Zip for Windows), right-click on the document and extract its contents.

Alternatively, you can simply rename your file by appending `.zip`, changing the file extension to make it more easily extractable.

Once unzipped check out the `word` folder. If there are comments you should see a comments file and related files. They're XML files that you can view with any text editor:

[image: docx folder structure with view of track changes comments file]

References:
1: [Track changes in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-XML-Formats-and-file-name-extensions-5200D93C-3449-4380-8E11-31EF14555B18)